# Send example of my work after interview based on questions from interview?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, new-job

I applied for a job some time ago and the company has contacted me and I had an interview over Skype. First part of interview was great, I answered all questions easily and they were pleased.

For the second part they asked me about technology that I have stated in my resume as something that I have worked with, but very little and I think that it was clear that I am not an expert. I have repeated that during interview and agreed to try to answer a few questions. I knew half the answers right away and guessed a quarter more (I made it clear that it was a guess, I explained why that is my guess, etc.). After that, their question was would I be willing to learn it more if they hired me and I said yes (and I really would be).

It was a few days since that interview now. I have taken a look at some documentation about that technology and build small example application by using what I have learned. Now I am thinking if it is a good idea to send this example to show them what I have learned and, more importantly that I am willing to learn it.

What do you think? Would this be considered a bit push or would I score some additional points?

Answer (score 4):

I have a friend who got a job by doing exactly that!  At the end of her interview, she had asked if the interviewer had any concerns that would prevent him from recommending her for the job, and he cited her inexperience in a particular programming language.  She went home, learned the basics, coded up a toy example, and sent it to them, saying that she hoped it would demonstrate that she was serious about, and capable of, learning the required skills.  She got the job.  (She had been out of the job market for many years as a full-time at-home parent prior to getting that job.)

So, draft a quick "cover letter" stating that you've gone ahead and started refreshing (or improving) your knowledge of the technology, and have built a small example application in the process, and you hope that by sharing it you can relieve any concerns they might have about your motivation and ability to come up to speed on the technology.

Good luck!

Comment: While I agree with the idea of sending them the application (it shows proactivity), the OP's situation is different: the interviewer did not suggest that he might not get the job. So maybe this strategy may backfire and make the interviewer think he's a bit desperate, don't you think?

Comment: To me it looks motivated, not desperate.  The OP knows that he had a good interview overall, but that he did not present a high level of competence on a desired technology.  Following up with evidence that he is willing and able to quickly come up to speed seems very appropriate. If the OP has not yet thanked the interviewer for the interview, he can even wrap it into a thank you note.

Comment: I wouldn't send the sample of work directly. What I would do is ship the sample of work to a githun repo, and send them the link to that repo. There is an element of risk if the code were viewed as less than optimal in terms of being well architectd and well written, but the prospective employer seems to be willing with the risk of hiring someone inexperienced anyway.

Comment: @l19 - anything is possible, but I cannot even imagine reacting to a candidate going the extra mile to prove their determination by thinking "wow, this guy is a bit desperate, better not hire him"

Answer (score 2):

> What do you think? Would this be considered a bit push or would I
>   score some additional points?

Since you feel that one of the key questions in the minds of the interviewer is your willingness and ability to learn this technology, it makes perfect sense to demonstrate your ability to do so.

I don't think this is pushy at all. It you way to see "See. Not only am I willing to learn this technology - I have already started to learn!"

This is a great technique, and could make you stand out over other applicants.

Two things to consider. First, make sure this is a really good example application. No bugs. No typos, etc. If necessary, have someone who is expert in the technology look it over to make sure it's valid.

Second, make sure you don't ask too much time of your interviewers in looking over this application. Make it easy for them to install, use, and review.